# how to set the transmission range of a node under Veins 2.0?

Tags: omnet++

I am wondering how to correctly set the transmission range of a node under Veins 2.0, i thought that i was doing it right, but i am afraid to be wrong.

So, i need some clarifications regarding parameters defined in *.ini file:

```
*.connectionManager.pMax = 24.34mW # =>>> parameters to set the max interference distance by the global manager module  
*.connectionManager.sat = -80dBm # =>>> parameters to set the max interference distance by the global manager module

*.**.nic.phy80211p.maxTXPower = 24.34mW  # =>>> what is the role of this parameter ? is it affecting the transmission range or only limiting the max TX Power ?

*.**.nic.mac80211p.txPower = 13.69mW # =>>> is it the parameter along to sensitivity that are responsible of changing transmission range ?
*.**.nic.phy80211p.sensitivity = -80dBm #for changing maximum transmission range
```

So, what is the difference between maxTXPower & txPower ? and how can i change the transmission range ? by changing the first one, the latter or both of them ?

thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`maxTXPower` is not used for the IEEE 802.11p model of Veins 2.0.

For an in-depth discussion of the concept of *transmission range* in Veins, please refer to the discussions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31079686/4707703.

For an in-depth discussion on calculating the *interference range* in Veins, please refer to the discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728592/4707703.