# Reduce the coverage area between vehicles

Tags: omnet++, veins

I need to reduce the coverage area of communication between vehicles. Should I reduce values of these parameters in omnetpp.ini?

```
*.**.nic.phy80211p.sensitivity = -89dBm
*.**.nic.phy80211p.maxTXPower = 10mW
*.**.nic.phy80211p.thermalNoise = -110dBm
```

If not, which parameters can I modify please?

Comment: Is this question answered?

Answer (score 2):

If by coverage area you mean communication range, the short answer is yes, you can modify these parameters to reduce the communication range (which I'd probably do by lowering the maximum transmission power). Alternatively, you can change the channel properties (in `config.xml`) by adding a corresponding analog model that has the behavior you're looking for. I recommend having a look at the [Two-Ray Interference model](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/modules/#tworay) and the [Obstacle Shadowing model](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/modules/#obstacles), which are part of VEINS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I will try your solution.

Comment: I tried to decrease the value of the maximum transmission power but it does not change my results in my simulation, I need to define the radius of the communication between vehicles (in my case they are bikes) to 75m, which parameters of NIC given in Veins can I modify to do it please?

Answer (score 1):

In the current Veins version (i.e. 4.5) you can also reduce the [`maxInterfDist`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.5/examples/veins/omnetpp.ini#L72) of the *ConnectionManager* which will result in overall less vehicles getting an AirFrame given to their NICs which they then try to decode. However, this only decreases the distance of the best possible communication (i.e. without buildings in LOS, etc.) and not the average distance which usually is way smaller due to fading effects and buildings.

Comment: Thank you for this information, I am working with Veins-4a2. I will try to execute my simulation Veins-4.5.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, the maxTXPower and maxInterfDist do not affect the coverage area between vehicles. You should modify the "*.**.nic.mac1609_4.txPower" and "***..nic.phy80211p.sensitivity". For a better understanding, you may check the answer from Christoph Sommer in this thread: [how to set the transmission range of a node under Veins 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841537/how-to-set-the-transmission-range-of-a-node-under-veins-2-0)