# How can a node reach only 50 meters of signal coverage in the veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

In my work I use a manhattan grid that has 9 frames (3x3). Each frame is 200 meters high and 200 meters wide.

In the model used there are no polygons that represent buildings or anything else that may interfere with the signal.

I need to reduce the signal so that it reaches only 50 meters.

Using the default configuration of veins 5.0's omnetpp.ini file and calculating `(bsm1->getSenderPos() - mobility->getPositionAt(simTime())).length()`, where `getSenderPos()` is the position received of a knot
and `getPositionAt(simTime())` and the position of the requesting node, I got a distance of 6m to 527m between the node that requested the geographical position and the nodes that sent this information.

I later changed the values ​​of `txPower` and `noiseFloor`, but I still could not get to the desired 50 meters.

Looking at this link [Reduce the coverage area between vehicles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933125/reduce-the-coverage-area-between-vehicles), it has been said that changing`maxInterfDist` can help.

What adjustments could I make or what would I need to understand better to make these adjustments?

Comment: You say that you suspect changing the maximum interf. distance might help and I see little reason why it should not. Have you tired?

Comment: @ChristophSommer I apologize if my question seems silly.

Comment: Even changing `txPower` to `5mW` and doing the calculation described above, the distance between two nodes reached 232m.

The reason I want a distance of up to 50 meters is because I want to find neighboring nodes to that distance to perform a geographic routing.

I also changed the values ​​of the `minPowerLevel` and `noiseFloor` parameters, but there seems to be a limit to changing these values.

I gradually increased and decreased the values ​​of these parameters until nothing was received.

But I could not get close to the desired value.

Comment: Now I’m confused. You were just talking about changing `maxInterfDist`, I said to give it a shot, whereupon you answered you tried `minPowerLevel`, `noiseFloor`, and `txPower` instead and it did not work. Why not try changing `maxInterfDist`?

Comment: As previously answered for osga, the `txPower` as `1.5mW` reaches a distance between nodes of 138.447m. In the new tests I kept the `txPower` parameter as`1.5mW`. I also changed the default value of `maxInterfDist` to the values ​​of `1000m, 2000m, 3000m, 4000` and `5000m`. However,  the largest distance between the nodes remained `138.447m`.

Comment: So, what you are saying is increasing the maximum distance allowed did not decrease the maximum distance reached? Seems fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking to model radio communication much more abstractly than Veins currently does: rather than calculating a receive probability (i.e., 25%) based on how well a vehicle receives a transmission (particularly when compared with sources of noise and interference), it seems you want to 100% receive anything transmitted within 50m, and definitely not receive anything further away than that. Such a simple model is currently not offered in Veins, but you can approximate it by simply discarding any information further than 50m away, for example, in your application -- or by setting the `maxInterfDist` of your ConnectionManager, as this defines the maximum distance at which two radios will interact (desired or undesired). See https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.7.1/src/veins/base/connectionManager/ConnectionManager.ned#L28 for details

Comment: I simply discarded any information from more than 50 m away. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I got these values (with veins-4.4):
(txPower - distance):
(20 mW - 531 m), (10 mW - 381 m), (5 mW - 270 m), (2 mW - 181 m)

Maybe with a txPower below 2 mW you get 50 m.

Comment: Setting the values below for `txPower` I got:

`1.8mW` = Maximum distance between nodes of 164.659m.

  `1.7mW` = Maximum distance between nodes of 141.339m.

`1.6mW` = Maximum distance between nodes of 139,754.

`1.5mW` = Maximum distance between nodes of 138,447.

`1.4mW` = No message has been received with node coordinates.