# Dynamical transmission range in the ieee802.11p module

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm a MRs student , i use sumo 0.25.0 and veins 4.4 within omnet++ 5.0 .I'm working in the IEEE0802.11p module. Including my proposition i will use a formula that change the transmission range calculator into dynamical calculator which communicate with the simulation to get information from it like (mean speed, average distance from front-bumper to front-bumper between vehicles ...).

here is [the transmission range formula that I will use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucVum.png)  and the
[Article containing the formula](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/2014/718698/)

my question is where can i find the transmission range calculator and where can I put my code in the application layer or in the mac layer?

Ps:I already read all the topics about the transmission range in veins here and in the google group but I can't find a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veins does not use the concept of a transmission *range* (in the sense of a fixed range that vehicles can communicate - sometimes also called a unit disk radio model). Instead, Veins compares usable received power to noise and interference, then (based on this ratio) derives a probability of packet reception.

See related questions (and answers) for questions revolving around how to set (and use) the transmit power:

- [how to set the transmission range of a node under Veins 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35841537/4707703)
- [Maximum transmission range vs maximum interference distance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31712578/4707703)
- [Vehicles Receive Beacon Messages outside RSU Range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31079102/4707703)